# Selecting multiple items in DataGrid on click

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

In an WPF `DataGrid` I want to select multiple items when clicking on an item. I tried doing this by manually setting the `DataGrid`s `SelectedItems` in the `CurrentCellChanged`-event and in the `SelectionChanged`-event, but the `SelectedItems` will be reset after the event handling. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `DataGrid` properties like this.

```
SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow"
```

You can write something like this in the `SelectionCellsChanged` event. Where `ObservableCollection<OwnObject>` is setted as `ItemsSource` of my `DataGrid`.

```
private void dgTest_SelectedCellsChanged( object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e )
{
    dgTest.SelectedItems.Add( ( dgTest.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<OwnObject> )[0] );
}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! For me it works even without explicitly setting setting the `SelectionMode` and `SelectionUnit`, but I'm not sure if someone set these as the default values for the whole application or if they are always the default values.

Comment: You're welcome. If `SelectionMode` not setted to `Extended` we cann't modify `SelectedItems`, so maybe it is setted somewhere or default.